# CQL2/CQL3 Cassandra Error on PHP

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra, cql3, cqlsh

While executing this code in PHP:

```
$db_nosql = new PDO('cassandra:host=127.0.0.1;port=9160;cqlversion=3.0.0');
```

I got a error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>
> 'CQLSTATE[HY000] [2] Cannot execute/prepare CQL2 statement since the
>   CQL has been set to CQL3(This might mean your client hasn't been
>   upgraded correctly to use the new CQL3 methods introduced in Cassandra
>   1.2+).'
>
> in /home/web/site/Test/page.php:202 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/web/site/Test/page.php(202): PDO->exec('USE mailing') #1 {main}
>   thrown in /home/web/site/Test/page.php on line 202

I don't know what I am supposed to do in this situation. Does that means that the syntax is incorrect ?

Thank you.

Comment: please read it again `This might mean your client hasn't been upgraded correctly to use the new CQL3 methods introduced in Cassandra 1.2+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try the [library](http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/). It uses the native protocol and does not require other libraries.